# Properties of quadrilaterals resulting from perspective projection of rectangle of known aspect ratio

Tags: computer-science, projective-geometry, computational-geometry, computer-vision

Given list of quadrilaterals (from image processing), are there any properties/calculations that can filter out those that are not perspective projection of a target rectangle of **specific aspect ratio**?

For example, **a square** cannot be the image of **an A4 paper**. Can we generalize this concept to filter out more quadrilaterals?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398632/relationship-of-aspect-ratio-to-the-homography-matrices-between-a-rectangle-and

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339924/compute-ratio-of-a-rectangle-seen-from-an-unknown-perspective

Comment: “For example, a square cannot be the image of an A4 paper.” Why not?

Comment: @amd: Because our intuition tells us that there must be foreshortening resulting in the more distant edge appearing shorter than the closer edge, which must be the case for the distance between the edges to become equal to the width. And if there's not that some parameter must be ∞. So if our intuition is wrong then the answer to "why?" must be much more enlightening than the answer to "why not?"

Comment: @amd: The only case I can think of is if the projection is Orthographic. OrthographicProj(A4Paper) can be Square, but PerspectiveProj(A4Paper) cannot

Comment: OK. That’s a good starting point. Can you come up with anything that distinguishes the result of a finite central projection of a rectangle from one with a viewpoint at infinity (a so-called affine camera)? My guess is that parallelograms that are not similar to the rectangle can’t be produced by finite central projections, but, with the restriction that the source rectangle doesn’t intersect the camera’s plane, you can get any other convex quadrilateral. The aspect ratio will only come into play in rejecting rectangular images.

Comment: Having thought about this some more, I believe that you’re going to need to know something about the camera’s intrinsic matrix to do any filtering. My previous guess basically assumed square pixels and no skew, but in general the intrinsic matrix will add an affine transformation to the cascade. You can still filter out *most* parallelograms, but knowing which ones to keep requires knowing the details of that extra transformation. I suspect that other quads could be rejected if you knew the camera’s frustrum, too.